# How do I use data from one function in another function in python?

Tags: python, function

Hello I am pretty new to python and I want to do the following:

I have a function that opens a file, reads the file, closes the file and returns the data:

```
def getFastaFromFile(filename):
    """ Read a fasta file (filename) from disk and return
    its full contents as a string"""
    inf=open(filename)
    data=inf.read()
    inf.close()
    return data
```

The data that is being returned are a few lines with strings.

What I want to do is have another function that uses the data from the first function and perform the `.readlines()`, `.readline()` and `.count()` commands

My second function:

```
def printTableFromFasta(fastarec):
    a= data.readlines()
    for i in range(a)
        b= data.readline()
        c= b.count('A')
        print(c)
```

As output I would like to print the amount of times string "A" appears for every line from the data. The problem I get with this code is that the data doesn't get recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass the data you are wanting to read into the second function, like so

```
def printTableFromFasta(data):
```

In order to get this from your first function, try returning the entire contents of the file

```
def getFastaFromFile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inf: # handles open and close
        data = inf.readlines()       # Returns the entire file as a list of strings
    return data
```

Your function call will look something like this

```
printTableFromFasta(getFastaFromFile(filename))
```

Then, in your second function, you don't need to call `readlines`, it's already a list.

```
def printTableFromFasta(data):
    for line in data            # look at each line
        print(line.count('A'))  # count 'A'
```

**Edit:**
To only read from the second function and not touch the first function

```
def printTableFromFasta(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inf: # handles open and close
        for line in inf.readlines()  # look at each line
            print(line.count('A'))   # count 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you Groger, this works, but is there a way to do this without changing the first function? I only want to do the reading commands in the second function.

Comment: @NawinNarain The file closes when `getFastaFromFile` ends. If you only want to change the second function, I can make an edit, but it involves only using the second function.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Groger! This is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the `data` variable in the first function is **local**. It cannot be accessed from outside the function it is defined in.

For example, the `getName()` function returns a variable which is locally called `data` but you access the value by calling the function.

```py
def getName(user_id):
    data = "Your name is " + str(user_id)
    return data 

# Throws an error, because data in undefined 
name = getName("Bobby")
print(data)

# Working code, prints "Your name is Bobby"
name = getName("Bobby")
print(name)
```

There are no rules against calling one function from inside another. 
Instead of `a = data.readlines()` try `a = getFastaFromFile("dna.fasta')` as well as changing `data = inf.read()` to `data = inf.readlines()`